# Adding events to my google calender using php

Tags: php, zend-framework, events, google-calendar-api

In my database i inserted some events.I want to add this events to my google calender from database.
How can i do this?

I downloaded the zend frameworking code:

```
http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata from this link.
```

But i dont know how to use it or how to integrate it with application?

How can i integrate it with my application in php.?

If there is any code for adding events to my google calender  without using  zend code?
Give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to download a complete library if you just need to insert some calendar items. You'd be better to roll your custom solution - this is also better to get acquinted with Google API programming. See the example on http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#creating_events. You just need to perform a POST request. Remember that in order to do so, you first have to login too Google - see the example here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php. These two links combined should make it fairly easy to accomplish what you want.

Comment: i want to insert event to google calnder using php code from my application site